# How can I write Spanish accents on my Dell XPS Studio 16 keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, dell-xps, input-languages, spanish

I state the model number because generally you would type ALT +  to type a letter from another language. But you would have to use the numerical pad with NumLock on.

Most laptops usually have the numerical pad over the letters, which can be accessed using the Fn key. The XPS studio 16 doesn't.

I was wondering, does anyone know anyway to type Spanish accents (accents of any language) without access to the numerical pad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your keyboard layout to "US International" and certain keys become "dead keys" (<kbd>~</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> -> **ñ**, <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> -> **é**, etc.). You'll need to double up to enter the character normally though (<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> -> **"**), so you can use a keystroke to switch between keyboard layouts for when you don't need the accents.

Comment: that's awesome thanks! What I've done is set it as a separate keyboard layout. And then I can put different shortcut keys to switch between the languages.

Comment: Does this help for typing upside question or exclamation marks? (like ¿ or ¡)

Answer (score 0):

For just the occasional character or symbol *CopyPasteChar.com* is a neat solution and for re-assignation of a keys autohotkey (involves some simple macro coding) does the job.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can type ñ by hitting `shift ~ n`
Try it. There must be more... (like accents)

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

Go to `Settings` from the Windows icon at bottom left.  Click on `Time and Language`, then `Region and Language`.

You should see something like `English (United States)`. Click on it and a button labeled `Options` will appear.

Click on the `Options` button. Now you will see an option to `Add a Keyboard` (or `Add an Input Method`). Click on that and then scroll down the list until you see `United States International`. Click to add it to your language bar (should be in the system tray).

After that:
~ + n -> ñ
' = a -> á

I found this here: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/us-international-keyboard-for-windows-10/f0dc89e9-2373-42af-bb2e-f50b8a69a13a?auth=1

Comment: This duplicates another answer (the accepted answer) and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.